# React Hover Navbar Transition

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

I'm currently improving a click to open navbar into a hover bar for a project.
onMousteEnter and onMouseLeave works fine, navbar opens and closes on mouse hover.
However my problem is that I can't add transition to it in css.. I am not sure what the problem could be.

My sidebar component:

```
export const Sidebar = props => {
  const { open, modules } = props;

  const onMouseEnter = useCallback(() => props.setMainMenuOpen(!open), []);
  const onMouseLeave = useCallback(() => props.setMainMenuOpen(open), []);

  return (
    <div
      open={setMainMenuOpen}
      onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter}
      onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave}
      className={`navigation ${open ? 'open' : ''}`}
      data-test-id="navigation"
      tabIndex="-1"
    >
      {modules.map(module => (
        <SidebarItem key={module.id} module={module} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
.navigation {
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    background: $color-sidebar-navigation-background;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1303;

    &.open {
        z-index: 1303;
        height: 100%;
        width: 6 * $navigation--width;
        box-shadow: 0 3px 14px 2px rgba(36, 36, 36, 0.12), 0 8px 10px 1px rgba(36, 36, 36, 0.14),
            0 5px 5px -3px rgba(36, 36, 36, 0.2);
    }
```

(everything works apart from transition)

I am trying to add the transition to the navigation className but it doesn't work.
Tried adding to &.open{} as well but still nothing...

What I am trying to achieve is that the navbar has an open and close transition for smoother user experience.

Comment: I think some of the CSS you didn't include might actually be helpful. Could you include the CSS for the `open` class?

Comment: I updated my question and added both navigation and open css. :)

Comment: could you show how you are trying to add the transition

Comment: @SandilRanasinghe 
I tried both to navigation and to open. transition: all 1s ease-out;

Comment: just to verify, you are trying to transition the width of your menu right?

Comment: @SandilRanasinghe, yes, to make it open smoother. so the width should transition smoother

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to add a transition to the width of your element, then you need to set the initial width of the element as well as the width it should change into. In general, for a transition, you need to specify the value of the property you're transitioning.
In your case adding a width value to .navigation should make the transition work. Hope this helped.

Comment: here is a sample with some of your code https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-currying-dsq80n?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Great. Other question regarding this. The width is a variable, so I added the variable to the .navigation, it is 52px so when closed I have only icons and overflow is hidden. When opening up the overflow is actually the labels. Transition doesn't do anything to them, they pop up quite quickly and since the width transition 0.5s and labels come up in 2 rows until the nav reaches the set width. So basically the labels for a short period of time visible in 2lines and then jumps into 1 as soon as the width of the nav bar allows is, and it looks weird. What transition could I set for the labels?

Comment: try adding a `white-space: nowrap` to the elements inside the menu

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add visibility: 1 when it's opened and visibility: 0, otherwise. In that case your transition property would be applied to visibility of element.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work, also in the meantime I added the navigation css so it might be more helpful how it works now.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/p8rv26by/ is it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

1. className={open ? 'navigation' : ''}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Nope, sorry I updated my question with the current css, but navigation has to be there in both cases, open and close